# How can I wire this ceiling light correctly?

Tags: electrical

I have a ceiling light that decided to not to work.
On inspection I found bare wires were sticking out under cover. 
I immediately turned off the light circuits at the switch board.
What I found was the light circuit wiring intact but the wires had been twisted together to join to the light fixture.
The light fixture has three wires blue, brown and green/yellow.
The house wiring has red and black.
I need to know which wires should be joined in an approved joiner so the light works correctly. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Wiring colour conventions can vary worldwide, so as you don't state where you are located, it's not possible to give a definitive answer.

In the UK for example (for single phase wiring), convention would have the live wire as brown (new colour) or red (old colour) and the neutral wire as blue (new colour) or black (old colour). It was not uncommon to see appliances using the new colours while fixed wiring still used the old colours, until the new colour scheme was adopted for fixed wiring (around 2004).

If you are in any doubt at all, sound advice would be to contact a competent electrician to do the work for you.